# How to add two primary keys in a table?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping

**SalutationMst.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SalutationMst")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class SalutationMst  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = true )///////////////id
    private Long id;
    //@Id
     @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, length=15)///////////////code
    private String code;
     @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length=15)////////////////name
    private String name;
    //private long genderid;
     @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)////////////////active
    private Boolean active;

    //@ManyToOne(targetEntity=GenderMst.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @ManyToOne
    //@JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
    private GenderMst genderMst;
    //getters snd setters
}
```

here String code should also be pk. String id is auto-generated but code is not. And by coming exp I need to specify code is repeating, for that I need code as a pk.

**GenderMst.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "GenderMst")
public class GenderMst {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = true,length=15)
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true,length=15)
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: You don't. you can have only one primary key. You can have a composite primary key, though. Google on that.

Comment: And why would you make code part of the PK, since i already uniquely identifies a Salutation? If you want code to be unique, then add a unique constraint on code. No need to make it part of the PK to do that.

Comment: I forgot about unique identifiers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this could be that you can create a separate class for `Composite Primary Key` and use it as `EmbeddedId` like:

```
@Embeddable
public class SalutationMstId  {
   private Long id;
   private String code;

   //constructors

   //getter setters
}
```

and use it like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SalutationMst")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class SalutationMst  {
     @EmbeddedId
     private SalutationMstId id;
     @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length=15)////////////////name
    private String name;
    //private long genderid;
     @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)////////////////active
    private Boolean active;

    //@ManyToOne(targetEntity=GenderMst.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @ManyToOne
    //@JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
    private GenderMst genderMst;
    //getters snd setters
}
```

Read more at [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys)